# html.fromhtml android color font from attribut

Tags: android, text, fonts, attributes

I have an application with different themes accessible. The color of a part of the text may vary depending on the theme. But when I use a color attribute that varies according to the theme, the color is not correct: the text is written in black instead of the desired color.

the set color with `"font color="#307CA4""` is ok 
but with font `"color=?color_txt_red"` not work.
why?

Part of code used:

file string.xml :

```
<resources> 
    <string name="txt_show" formatted="false"><![CDATA[<font color="#307CA4" ><b>Liste des messages reçus : </b></font>Vous avez <font color=?color_txt_red>%d message </font>non lu]]></string>
</resources>
```

file color.xml :

```
<resources>
    <color name="red_1">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="red_2">#c3051f</color>
</resources>
```

file style.xml :

```
<attr name="color_txt_red" format="reference|color" />

<style name="theme_1" >
    <item name="color_txt_red">@color/red_1</item>
</style>

<style name="theme_2" >
    <item name="color_txt_red">@color/red_2</item>
</style>
```

part of file testMain.java:

```
int nbMessage = 0;
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.txt_show, nbMessage)));
```

image valid
[image: image valid red_1]

image error
[image: image error]

May anyone could help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: You can use a spannablestring builder instead

Comment: @Raghunandan : yes but that means that you have to put several string in place for a sentence because the size of the text to be red is dynamic. There is not a solution to work with a single string?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986834/3998710