# Change color and make bold part of a TextView in xml

Tags: android, html, xml, textview

This is my *xml* code in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/already_have_an_account" />
```

and in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="already_have_an_account">Already have an account? <font color='#FF6200EE'>Log In</font></string>
```

With this code I can change the color of *"Log In"* text but I wanna make it bold too in *xml* code, not *Java*.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML in string resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667319/html-in-string-resource) Also [Highlighting Text Color using Html.fromHtml() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730706/highlighting-text-color-using-html-fromhtml-in-android).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<b>`**Log In**`</b>` will make it. The string resource is to be as follows:

```
<string name="already_have_an_account">Already have an account? <font color='#FF6200EE'><b>Log In</b></font></string>
```

Here is more on [Styling with HTML markup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML).