# HTML tags in string for TextView

Tags: android

If I put simple HTML formatting tags, such as <b>...</b> into a string resource and display the string in a TextView, the expected formatting is applied. But how can I do this if I build up my own String and display it? If I do something like String str = "This is <b>bold</b>";, the actual tags get displayed -- not the expected bolding.

Do I have to run the string through some other method to cause the tags to be recognized as tags?

Comment: FWIW, here is a blog post where I list the tags supported by `Html.fromHtml()` in Android 2.1: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html  While not documented and therefore subject to change, it will give you an idea of what is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use [Html#fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String input = "<b>bold</b>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(input));
```

Comment: simple and clean solution!