# Android - two sentences, two styles, one TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am tyring to display a TextView that contains two sentences and I want them to be one after the other like this:

```
AAAAAA: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBB
```

where A... is the first word\part of sentence and B... is a second sentence.

the size of A... & B... isn't constant.

tried doing this:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        style="@style/f13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAAA: " />    
    <TextView 
            style="@style/f15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_text" />                
    </RelativeLayout>
```

but i got:

```
AAAAAA: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
        BBBBBBBBB
```

and i want the second (B...) sentence to continue below the first sentence (A...)
i should add that sentence A... & B... have different styles.

the style for A:

```
<style 
    name="f13">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_dark_emperor</item>
</style>
```

the style for B:

```
<style 
    name="f15">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_dark_emperor</item>
</style>
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you using 2 textviews for a reason? I think this can be easily done with a single TextView. That way the wrapping will be automatically done the way you want it.

Comment: have a look at using [SpanableString in a single TextView](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)

Comment: u said that the size of A&B are not constant..that means the value is dynamic rt?

Comment: i am using or better want to use, one textview

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try to use the [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) as follows:

```
String firstString = "AAAAAA: ";
String secondString = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";

SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(firstString + secondString);
stringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, firstString.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
stringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)), firstString.length() + 1,
            firstString.length() + secondString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

This will make the first sentence to be bold, and the second one coloured in red.

Comment: can i add support for styles ? i failed to mention that sentence A... and B... have different styles

Comment: Yes, you can use [TextAppearanceSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) as a parameter to setspan function to set the text color, size, style, and typeface.

Comment: i have tried so many solution but this one really helped me for doing  widget's texview in different colors for two sentences in single textview.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML tags to get the desired effect with a single text view. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546009/html-tags-in-string-for-textview) and [this](http://rickiedroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/different-font-style-using-html-tag-and.html) and also [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).

Comment: i want to add different styles for each sentence so i need support for layout styles

Comment: Did u checked the tags in commonsware blog that i had mentioned. There are many params to change the style of the text you want. Can't you use <font size="..." color="..." face="..."> for each sentence and get your problem solved?.. If you are still facing the issue don't hesitate to post what you tried with html tags

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML to display your text

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Comment: i want to add different styles for each sentence so i need support for layout styles

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAAA: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" />                
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this as xml.

Comment: as i mentioned A... & B... are not constant and differ

Comment: Then you can programatically set the text.

Comment: Ok...you need to style them programmatically. please specify what styling you want to give each of them?you can achieve that using SpannableString.

Comment: please refer answer of lexmiir.

Comment: can i add styles via SpannableString ?

Comment: please refer lexmiir's answer above.that is exactly what i want to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

By uing single textview only you will be able to do it. you just need to append two string in single textview.

```
textview.setText(first_text+":"+second_text);
```

Comment: i want to add different styles for each sentence so i need support for layout styles

Answer (score -1):

u have written the position of second text as right of first text.

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_text"
```

so as per my knowledge it is not possible to continue below the first sentence.it is always writing the second text only in the right side of first text.