# How to set double text style in textview in android?

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I am using a typeface as well as i want to make it bold but its not getting bold, how to set the text style when if set a typeface in text.

```
century_gothic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "century_gothic.ttf");
TextView dialog_text = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textdialog);
dialog_text.setText(text);
dialog_text.setTypeface(CustomDialog.century_gothic);
dialog_text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Comment: you want to apply two differnt styles to your textview?

Comment: i want century_gothic style with bold text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618835/apply-two-different-font-styles-to-a-textview

Comment: then you have to look for century gothic bold.ttf

Comment: this can be `dialog_text.setTypeface(CustomDialog.century_gothic | Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

`dialog_text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);`

use:

```
Typeface century_gothic_bold = Typeface.create(century_gothic, Typeface.BOLD);  
dialog_text.setTypeface(century_gothic_bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
dialog_text.setTypeface(CustomDialog.century_gothic | Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **getTypeface()** method like this:

```
dataTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle);
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");
dataTitle.setTypeface(font);
dataTitle.setTypeface(dataTitle.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
```