# Any way to set span directly to spanable text?

Tags: android, spannable

This may be a blunder,But I need to know... :)
Iam develeoping an android application,In in I want to display two type face in a single textview and found [this One very useful,A custom typeface span that extends typeface span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618835/apply-two-different-font-styles-to-a-textview), 
As per my understanding , we are creating a spannable as follows using two words

```
String firstWord = "first ";
String secondWord = "second";
// Create a new spannable with the two strings
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(firstWord+secondWord);
```

then sets two type face to that words using our custom span  like this

```
// Set the custom typeface to span over a section of the spannable object
spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif",CUSTOM_TYPEFACE), 0,              
firstWord.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif",SECOND_CUSTOM_TYPEFACE),   rstWord.length(), secondWord.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Now my question, I have a **large amount of text** so If i am able to put the **spans directly in my text its will be a more easy** for us ,**is that possible to put spans directly** to the text like we put `<b>bold </b>` as my need is to use my custom typeface span  like `<typeface1> sample </typeface1> <typeface2> Doc </typeface2>`.

**WHAT I NEED IS,  DIRECTLY APPLY THE CHANGE TO TEXT WHAT THE SET SPAN DO TO THE TEXT**

Is that possible, if possible what i need to write as span in my text,How can I achieve this.. or am i compleatly wrong ?

Thank you for all

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display TWO TYPE FACES in a single text view ?

Comment: yes i want to display TWO TYPE FACES in a single text view

Comment: You can use bold typeface. like gothic_century_bold

Comment: Sorry i cant get  that, I need to display two different languages

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer but what you asked for is pretty easy.

For instance, lets say we want to change everything between quotation marks into italic font.

```
    String s =  "\"Hello my name is Edward\" Hola, my nombre es Edward";        
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(s);
    while (m.find()) {        
      int textLocation = text.indexOf(m.group(1)); 

      // Set the custom typeface to span over a section of the spannable object       
       spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif",my_italic_font),
       textLocation-1, textLocation + m.group(1).length(),spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);                   

      // Set the text of a textView with the spannable object
      TextView textbox = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardtextbox);

    }
    textbox.setText( spannable );
```

Result of `s` would be

*"Hello my name is Edward"* Hola, my nombre es Edward

Now instead of quotation marks you would use a regex pattern for tags like `<b>bold </b>`;

And you could also remove the tags afterwards with a simple `.replace()`;

Comment: Thank you Edvard for the answer, this is not the Thing I want,In answer we are using  spannable.setSpan to set the span to desired index, I want to avoid setspan statement from my code...and directly apply the typeface to text itself without any further modification...Soryy may be it's a blunder :)