# In Android, how to specify different text style in setText( )?

Tags: android, textview, settext

I want to create a setText that derives one textView but contains texts in different textStyle.

For instance, there are some codes below.And, I ask how to use different textStyle's in setText() without working on xml file.

```
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setText("The sum of numbers 1 to " + lastNumber + " is "+ sum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exactly searching for this:

[Apply two different font styles to a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618835/apply-two-different-font-styles-to-a-textview)

You can also check this

[Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Or if you only want to set one single typeface use this:

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
fonts/androidnation.ttf");
    TextView title .setTypeface(font);
```

Therefor the font must be in the font folder.