# How to apply multiple TypeFace on a single TextView depending on language?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-typeface

I have a single `TextView` with two languages: Arabic and English.

I have two different fonts, `arabic.ttf` and `english.ttf`.

I want to apply the two fonts to the single TextView and it should change the fonts depending upon the language.

For Arabic only arabic.ttf should be applied and for English english.ttf should be applied.

The problem is that both of them are in the same TextView so I am having trouble applying two fonts.

I checked the example of `SpannableStringBuilder`, but it did not help.

Please provide a working code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve what you want:

Create 2 folders:

- res/font-en
- res/font-ar

Put your english font file inside the `-en` folder and arabic font file inside `-ar` folder.

Rename the files in order to have the same name in each folder e.g.

```
textViewFont.ttf
```

In your TextView add `android:fontFamily="@font/textViewFont"`

This way, when your app is opened, the XML framework will load the font based on the current Locale

Comment: i want both the fonts at the same time

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this with only one view, since the style is applied to the view object itself, rather than the text.

Comment: ok, so when I apply arabic font,the english text is not affected.However the all the spaces in the english characters are gone.For example when i apply the arabic text,the arabic font changes but the english text which was "sample text font" is now being displayed as "sampletextfont".Why these spaces are gone?

Comment: Probably because the Arabic font is designed for Arabic text characters and this affects the English words by removing spaces in this case. But this is my opinion.

Comment: Did you understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be extending your custom typeface fonts to TypeFaceSpan and also use the SpannableString to help you get that fixed. The link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619371/8208341 , helped me.

Also split your textview texts into array of strings then loop through to apply your method created above.

Answer (score 0):

how about create new style `style-ar.xml` in `values-ar`

```
<style name="my_arbic_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>
```

and in your layout:

```
<TextView
    android:text="khaled djeriou"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical`
    app:theme="@style/my_arbic_style"/>
```

i hope this work