# Multiple fonts to a single custom TextView

Tags: android, xml, fonts, textview

How can we use different styles of Roboto(or any other) font (Roboto-Regular, Roboto-Thin, Roboto-Bold etc) in a single custom `TextView`.

One of the methods to do this programmatically is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619371/2550246). But how to achieve this if we want to change style using XML.

Can this be done using custom attributes like this?

```
<com.project.abc.customviews.XYZTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        app:type="thin" />
```

I don't want to make different java files for each type. Another method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197867/2550246) but this has issues regarding memory. Looking for a good solution.

Comment: you will have to do it programmatically. in xml you can declare it once only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I achieved:

1. Created a custom TextView

   ```
   public class CaptainTextView extends TextView {
   private HashMap<String, Typeface> mTypefaces;

   public CaptainTextView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public CaptainTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   if (mTypefaces == null) {
       mTypefaces = new HashMap<>();
   }

   if (this.isInEditMode()) {
       return;
   }

   final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CaptainTextView);
   if (array != null) {
       final String typefaceAssetPath = array.getString(
           R.styleable.CaptainTextView_customTypeface);

       if (typefaceAssetPath != null) {
           Typeface typeface;

           if (mTypefaces.containsKey(typefaceAssetPath)) {
               typeface = mTypefaces.get(typefaceAssetPath);
           } else {
               AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
               typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, typefaceAssetPath);
               mTypefaces.put(typefaceAssetPath, typeface);
           }

           setTypeface(typeface);
       }
       array.recycle();
   }
   }

   public CaptainTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       if (mTypefaces == null) {
           mTypefaces = new HashMap<>();
       }

       if (this.isInEditMode()) {
           return;
       }

       final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CaptainTextView);
       if (array != null) {
           final String typefaceAssetPath = array.getString(
               R.styleable.CaptainTextView_customTypeface);

           if (typefaceAssetPath != null) {
               Typeface typeface;

               if (mTypefaces.containsKey(typefaceAssetPath)) {
                   typeface = mTypefaces.get(typefaceAssetPath);
               } else {
                   AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
                   typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, typefaceAssetPath);
                   mTypefaces.put(typefaceAssetPath, typeface);
               }

               setTypeface(typeface);
           }
           array.recycle();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Declared a custom attribute

   ```
   <resources>
   <declare-styleable name="CaptainTextView">
       <attr name="customTypeface" format="string" />
   </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
3. Used in XML

   ```
   <com.project.captain.customviews.CaptainTextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Welcome"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       app:customTypeface="fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf" />
   ```

Voila!