# How to implement "Rich Edittext" in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, number-formatting, spannablestring, bulletedlist

I am trying to implement "Rich Edittext" in android, i want to apply effect like "Bold, italic, underline, Bullet span, Number Indent span etc..." effect. So, Somehow i have completed Bold, Italic and other functionality but i am not able to complete Bullet and NumberIndent.

I did lot's of research and checked so many example and other stuff's but couldn't complete the task. I have downloaded some style class from below link but i am not able to understand how can i use this class in my code.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/text/style/BulletSpan.java?av=f

So anyone here who have done some similar task or anything else which lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TextTypeOption {

    public final static int BOLD = 1;
    public final static int ITALIC = 2;
    public final static int UNDERLINE = 3;

    public TextTypeOption(int option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public int getOption() {
        return this.option
    }

    public boolean isBold() {
       return option == BOLD;
    }

    public boolean isItalic() {
       return option == ITALIC;
    }

    public boolean isUnderline() {
       return option == UNDERLINE;
    }
}
```

Define a TextTypeOption value :

> TextTypeOption option = new TextTypeOption(TextTypeOption.BOLD);//for bold

1)  use the [Html.fromText(String text)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))

```
    if(option.isBold()) {
        text = text.replace(selectedText , "<b>"+ (selectedText + "</b>");
        et.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }

    if(option.isItalic()) {
        text = text.replace(selectedText , "<i>"+ (selectedText + "</i>");
        et.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }

    if(option.isUnderline()) {
        text = text.replace(selectedText , "<u>"+ (selectedText + "</u>");
        et.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }
```

2) use the [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)

```
    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

    if(option.isUnderline()) {
        span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),startSelection, endSelection , 0);
    }

    if(option.isBold()) {
        span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection ,  0);
    }

    if(option.isItalic()) {
        span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection , 0);
    }
    et.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

P.S. I think it's not the elegant way but it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you give me any working example or simple demo code, because i am not able to figure it out what are these "option", "text", "selectedText" etc.. variable for. Sorry, i am new in android and i don't know much about it... I am trying to implement something like this URL kind of application, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hly.notes

Comment: Good, Thank you for the update, what about Bullet and Number Indent  Span, how can i implement this functionality ???

Comment: @user3660803 in that case you need to implement your own view because tools of SDK doesn't tak to you any opportunity to make this in EditText.

Comment: Kind of late, but ul is supported. See [the list of supported HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45146556/6296561). Alternatively, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aftabsikander/0b188c55a4e7066f9e14) on creating custom spannables.