# How to format text coming from a text file to a textview in Android

Tags: android, file, textview

I have an app that is using text file to get text. I can get the text and put it in the Textview by reading from the file and appending it to the textview and that works just fine, but I would like to add formats to the text. Like making the header bold and so and so.

```
private void openFile()
{
    String tema = "Message";
    TextView temas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutorial);
    temas.setText(title);
    temas.setTextSize(25);

    temas.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("tutorials/tutorial1.txt");
        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        String text = new String(buffer);


        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(text);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html tags to display formatted text.For example

```
 String x ="Hello <b>World!</b>";
 rextView.setText(x);
```

for more info refer this answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754076/which-html-tags-are-supported-by-android-textview)

If you know which word you want to format then you can iterate the string till you find that word/character add the tag and add it back to the string. Another method would be to add special characters before that word you want to format in the file itself for example if i want to make my heading bold then i can add a character like '#' before that word so when i read the file i know which formatting i have to apply to which word.