# Android : Html.fromHtml() not showing output same as web

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I have attached screenshots for web and app.

In web

[image]

Inside textview

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` isn't supporting all HTML tags, check out supported list in [HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java#784) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754076/which-html-tags-are-supported-by-android-textview) SO topic. its very basic implementation which doesn't support e.g. nested `<span` tags (looks like) - closing tag `</span>` is closing ALL opened previously spans, not only last one (so your red background breaks after first span-styled letter, when orange-coloring-span is closed)

if you want full support of HTML content - use [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) and [`loadData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method