# How to load HTML content to Textview in Android

Tags: android, webview, textview

I am trying to add the html content to Android textview. I am using the following code to load.

```
TextView textView;

    String text = "<span style='color:#6D3078;font-family:'Quicksand',Medium;line-height:14px;font-size: 14px;font-weight:700;Width: 128px;Height:1px;Top:421px;Left:20px'><strong>Additional</strong> <strong>Benefits</strong></span><div style=\"border: 1px solid Gainsboro; height: 1px; width: 320px;\"></div><ul style=\"list-style: none; padding: 0;\"><li><span style=\"display: inline-block; width: 6px; height: 6px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #6D3078; margin-right: 10px;\"></span><span style='color:#3F3F3F;font-family:' Quicksand ',Medium;line-height:12px;font-size: 12px;font-weight:500;Width: 320px;Height:12px;'>Program</span></li><li><span style=\"display: inline-block; width: 6px; height: 6px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #6D3078; margin-right: 10px;\"></span><span style='color:#3F3F3F;font-family:' Quicksand ',Medium;line-height:12px;font-size: 12px;font-weight:500;Width: 320px;Height:12px;'>Individual</span></li><li><span style=\"display: inline-block; width: 6px; height: 6px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #6D3078; margin-right: 10px;\"></span><span style='color:#3F3F3F;font-family:' Quicksand ',Medium;line-height:12px;font-size: 12px;font-weight:500;Width: 320px;Height:12px;'>Self</span></li><li><span style=\"display: inline-block; width: 6px; height: 6px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #6D3078; margin-right: 10px;\"></span><span style='color:#3F3F3F;font-family:' Quicksand ',Medium;line-height:12px;font-size: 12px;font-weight:500;Width: 320px;Height:12px;'>Common</span></li></ul><a href=\"https://www.google.com\"><span style='color:#F37435;font-family:' Quicksand ',Medium;line-height:12px;font-size: 12px;font-weight:500;Width: 190px;Height:12px;'>Other Details & Program</span></a><p> </p><span style='color:#6D3078;font-family:' Quicksand ',Medium;line-height:14px;font-size: 14px;font-weight:700;Width: 148px;Height:14px;Top:421px;Left:20px'><strong>For Program</strong></span><p> </p><p> </p><p>Come with family <strong>Just</strong> Join with us.</p><p>\n";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview_android);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        } else {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
        }
    }
```

But some styles are not applied.

Output:

[image]

But When I load the same html text in webview I am getting the following output.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");
        }
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Please give some ideas to apply all styles in textview.

Comment: A TextView is no WebView.

Comment: Have you tried to pass Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY instead?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞSツ Yes.. Tried. No luck.

Comment: Try to add it in your Strings.xml inside of 
`<string name="html"><![CDATA[HERETHEHTML]]></string> ` and add this to your TextView setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞSツ..  I Tried your solution.  But not working.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞSツ .. Now I am trying with **Html.TagHandler**. If I am able to handle the tags by using this, I let you know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply can't

`TextView` and `Html.formHtml(..)` are supporting only some of tags, take a look in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754076/which-html-tags-are-supported-by-android-textview) which. its basically a quick workaround for handling most common tags, like `b` or `u`, for fast text formatting (instead of using `Spannable`s, which are way more complex and need more code to write)

if you need more complex HTML handling you have to use `WebView`

Comment: Yes. Finally we moved to webview.