# android/java replace string to bold or some color in webview in html

Tags: android, html, webview

i have a string ticker..
ticker="hdfc:123:-1.90 tcc:231:+1.3 as continue to hundreds of

ticker will get from the server. i just want to bold the name... so help me to find my solution.....

here is my code...

```
tiker = TickerConnection.getInstance().Ticker();

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);String summary = "<html><body><MARQUEE>"+tiker+"</MARQUEE></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: this was asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/android-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Answer (score 0):

hey following is ur solution... u jst have to add tag `<b>`

```
tiker = TickerConnection.getInstance().Ticker();

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);String summary = "<html><body><MARQUEE><b>"+tiker+"</b></MARQUEE></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```