# Place a hyperlink in the text of a checkbox?

Tags: android

I have a checkbox that has this text: "I agree to the terms and conditions". I need "terms and conditions" to be blue, underlined, and open a webpage when touched.

I did find the Linkify class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html), but this seems to turn URLs already in text into to links.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color the text blue and add an onClick Listener to it that launches the intent to view the URL. You can markup your text using HTML like syntax via `Html.fromHtml()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/android-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview/1533512#1533512) for better explanation and example.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do this only for the sub-string "terms and conditions"?

Answer (score 15):

Just use the string like

"I agree to the <a href="...">terms and conditions</a>"

and set movement method:

```
mCheckBoxTermsOfUse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTermsOfUse);
mCheckBoxTermsOfUse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

See [api demos](http://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.java) for details

Comment: If I add the function `setMovementMethod()`, I do not see the text immediately, but only after I clicked once.
Is there a solution?