# How to change the colour of text programmatically

Tags: android

I have a question about textviews in android.

What I want to do is have a row of text (probably will be in a textview) but it will be a row of letters for a learning game.

So level one would say "AAAAA" for example, but I want each letter to be a different colour, like blue, red, red, blue, black.

But I want to reuse the code, so in level 2, they would be different colours.
How would i go about changing the colours of these letters the way I want? I have about 30 levels, so it would be impractical to have a different layout for each one with the different text views.

I was thinking something, that it would be written something like this A[blue]A[red]A[black]
you know, the colour I want it to be in the square brackets beside the letter. Thanks!

EDIT: maybe defining the colours of the letters, then passing that onto a string, which would then get applied to a textview?

Comment: So far the only thing I've got working is creating a different textview for each letter, and setting its colour. but this is impractical as i have to then make a new layout for each level as the number of letters i'm showing is different each time. Sometimes there may even be words between the letters, like AAA Play AA, etc

Comment: So its been marked as a duplicate, and the answer there will create much more work, but I guess it'll have to do

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-two-different-colored-text/24039182#24039182