# How to get Spannable and its color from TextView to write a unit test

Tags: android, textview, robolectric

```
private void createStringEndingInRedColor(TextView tv, String word1, String word2) {
    Spannable word = new SpannableString(word1);
    tv.setText(word);

    Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString(word2);

    wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(mContext.getResources().getColor(Color.RED)), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.append(wordTwo);
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test (using Robolectric) for the TextView tv to ensure that wordTwo is Color.RED.  However, I only have a reference to TextView tv.  How does one go about such a task?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the color of the `Spannable` from `TextView` using `getSpans()` method

```
ForegroundColorSpan[] colorSpans = ((SpannableString)textView.getText()).getSpans(0, textView.getText().length(), ForegroundColorSpan.class);
assertTrue(colorSpans[0].getForegroundColor() == Color.RED)
```

Comment: I get a class cast exception unless I use a `SpannedString` instead of the `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Comment: Hey all, OP here.  In retrospect, this is not a good unit test (it tests the Android Framework).  Instead, create a new class: Colorizer.  then verify(mColorizer).changeSecondWordToRed(textView, word1, word2) was called.