# Why can't the font color be displayed when I read a string from resource?

Tags: android

I hope to set single TextView with two different colored text, I have the read the document

[Single TextView with multiple colored text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-two-different-colored-text)

Code A works well!

Code B get string from resource file, but the color of font can not be displayed, why?

**Code A**

```
 TextView my=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVTitleOld);
 String text = "<font color='#cc0029'>Hello</font> the <font color='#ffcc00'>world</font>";
 my.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

**Code B**

```
 TextView my=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVTitleOld);
 String text = getResources().getString(R.string.TitleOld);
  my.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


<string name="TitleOld"><font color='#cc0029'>Hello</font> the new <font color='#ffcc00'>world</font></string>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML code in `Strings.xml` should be stored in CDATA using something like

```
<![CDATA[html source code]]>
```

So, in short your code would be

```
<string name="TitleOld"><![CDATA[<font color=\'#cc0029\'>Hello</font> the new <font color=\'#ffcc00\'>world</font>]]></string>
```

This is because `<` is stored in the xml file as `&lt;`, `>` as `&gt;` and so on. `CDATA` maintance the actual text whatever you need to display.

Comment: Thanks! but your code don't work, it display ![CDATA[html source code]]

Comment: Use <string name="TitleOld">![CDATA[<font color='#cc0029'>Hello</font> the new <font color='#ffcc00'>world</font>]]</string>

Comment: Yes, I did use <string name="TitleOld">![CDATA[<font color='#cc0029'>Hello</font> the new <font color='#ffcc00'>world</font>]]</string> , but it don't work

Comment: Am sorry. I didnt test before posting. This will definitely work (just tested). `<string name="TitleOld"><![CDATA[<font color=\'#cc0029\'>Hello</font> the new <font
        color=\'#ffcc00\'>world</font>]]></string>`

Comment: And more, I hope to set new line in the <string name="TitleOld"> , but both \n and <\br> don't work. How can I do? Thanks! <string name="TitleOld"><![CDATA[<font color=\'#cc0029\'>Hello</font> the \n new new <\br> <font color=\'#ffcc00\'>world</font>]]></string>