# TextView with colored font

Tags: android, paragraph

**Lorem ipsum dolor** is a textview and indep of the rest.

How can I do this in Android?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, though I like this one the best -

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
 Spannable word = new SpannableString("Your message");        

 word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 TV.setText(word);
 Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString("Your new message");        

 wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 TV.append(wordTwo);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14936995/609782)