# How can i style just a specific part of timeformat?

Tags: android, datetime

how can i style just a part of a timeformat?
The hours and minutes shoud me in a darkblue and the rest in a lightblue.
It should be also in the users local format, like on this image.
[image]
Anyone know how to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can color parts of a `TextView` text in different colors using `Spannable`. See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-multiple-colored-text).

The example below shows how to get time string according to local format by calling the method `getTimeString(Context context, Date date)`.

All the methods in the example are static so you can put them in some `Utils` class and call it like `Utils.getTimeString(context, date)`.

```
public static String getTimeString(Context context, Date date) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(getTimePattern(context), currentLocale(context));
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

public static boolean is24HourTimeFormat(Context context) {
        return android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
    }

private static String getTimePattern(Context context) {
        return is24HourTimeFormat(context) ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm a";
    }

private static Locale currentLocale(Context context) {
        return context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
```