# Different font size and color of strings in the same TextView

Tags: android, string, textview

is it possible to change font size and color of string in the same textview .

For example :

```
 _______________
|_______________| --> this is my text view
```

**What i want to do**

```
________________
|ABC (red color) |
|abc(whitecolor) |
|________________|
```

And string should look like this  **"ABC\nabc"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the text color of TextView in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-the-text-color-of-textview-in-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Comment: [Real dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-multiple-colored-text)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SpannableStringBuilder`

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("Text1");
str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, str1.length(), 0);
builder.append(str1);

SpannableString str2= new SpannableString(appMode.toString());
str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, str2.length(), 0);
builder.append(str2);

TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setText( builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```