# how can i create a textview with two color text?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, textcolor

i want create a `TextView` and have two text or on text with two color...

i create this ;
[image]

and i want the sample shop color change to red and search in is blue...

my xml code :

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_bg"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
    android:drawableTint="@color/day_dark_blue"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:text="search in Sample Shop"
    android:textColor="@color/day_dark_blue"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-multiple-colored-text

Check if this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single TextView with multiple colored text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-multiple-colored-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SpannableString to achieve the same.

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("search in Sample Shop");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 9, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 10, 21, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString)

```
// in the .kt file
val spannable = SpannableString("search in the Sample Shop")
    
spannable.setSpan(
     ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 
     10, 20, 
     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

// 10, 20: start and end index of Sample Shop

myTextView.text = spannable
```

A helpful article: [Spantastic text styling with Spans](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568)