# How to set different colors for textview in recyclerview adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application i need to set different colors for text view in recycler view adapter class, can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: could you show some code where you are facing the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single TextView with multiple colored text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-multiple-colored-text)

Answer (score 1):

In your [`onBindViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)), obtain the text view  via the respective ViewHolder and simply call [`setTextColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextColor(int)) on it  with the appropriate color ( Ideally this could be based on the data at the specified `position` from [`onBindViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int))).

If you want different colors within a single text view, you could follow the link to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-multiple-colored-text) provided by @SebastienRieu in the comments.

I think this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-recyclerview-fundamentals#3) might be helpful for you.