# How to change the color of specific strings in TextView

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I have a scrollable TextView that has texts like this

```
...
Tom: sometext
Jack: anothertext
Sam: something
...
```

So I get this data as a JSON object, then I seperate the keys and values, then adding to a string. Then I set the text of TextView as this final string.

What I want is, I would like to make different colors for `Tom, Jack, Sam`. I have found HTML library but all solutions changes the whole TextView. I want to change specific parts of the text and since I get a JSON data first and I'm adding this JSON values to a string part by part, I thought I can do something like this `string += <HTML color change> JSON["key"] + JSON["anotherKey"]`.

Is it possible to change specific parts of the text of a TextView object?

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as this tag is used for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is an Android question and has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Comment: You mean that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094346/15298643) didn't work?

Comment: @javdromero yes that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at spannable Strings. You will probably end up with something like this.

```
val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder("Text " + JSON["key"])
spannable.setSpan(
    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
    5, // start
    5 + JSON["key"].length, // end
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
)
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans for more info regarding spans.

Note: this example is in Kotlin but it's pretty much the same in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text color in **TextView** using below code snippets.

```
val blackColor= ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)
val redColor= ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)

textView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color=\"$blackColor\">Welcome to </font> <font color=\"$redColor\">Stack Overflow </font>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Above code is in *kotlin* , its same as *Java* you can convert to Java.
*Hope it will work for you !*