# Android: How to display formated code in TextView?

Tags: android

I am writing an android application that will be displaying codes... specially java codes, or maybe jsp code as well. I was thinking about placing these codes in a TextView. However i dont know how to do this for android. I didnt find any tutorial or documentation on how to display formated text in a TextView. I know I can put html in there, so one direction would be format the code itself in html and then place it in the textview.

Is there a better way to do that?

Many thanks
T

Answer (score 1):

TExtView can't do all the formatting. HTML is the best guess.

Search for "Spannable HTML Textview Android" and you will get quite a few examples. Here is one.

[Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)