# Bold words in a string of strings.xml in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a long text in one of the strings at strings.xml. I want to make bold and change the color of some words in that text.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in terms of what you're trying to achieve overall?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You could basically use html tags in your string resource like:

```
<resource>
    <string name="styled_welcome_message">We are <b><i>so</i></b> glad to see you.</string>
</resources>
```

And use Html.fromHtml or use spannable, check the link I posted.

Old similar question: [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Comment: Also, depending how you use your resource string, you may need to put the bold/italic tags in a CDATA block so they don't get parsed until it's used by `Html.fromHtml()`: ... `<![CDATA[<b><i>so</i></b>]]>` ...

Comment: For anybody else who found the official Android documentation a bit too vague on this: if you use tags like <b> in your string resource, make sure you retrieve it using `getText(R.string.whatever)` rather than `getString(R.string.whatever)`

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `name` instead of `id`?

Comment: No Hendra, it should be name not id.

Comment: So no need for `Html.fromHtml` or `Spannable`. Just use `getText(R.string.whatever)` like @andygeers mentioned.

Comment: @andygeers `getText ` from Java file. How to do it If we are using it in layout xml?

Comment: @andygeers What can we do for a string like "My name is <b>%s</b>" which cannot use getText as it only accepts a single parameter?

Comment: Taylor, you can refer answer of Saga chorage, It worked with place holder text

Comment: In this answer, <b></b> tag stands for Bold, and <i></i> for Italic, so if someone just want bold words only needs to use the first tag

Comment: still, I'm facing an issue,
using %1$s between string inside the String.xml file. getString(v1, v2) can't replace with getText(v1, v2)

Comment: @Taylor we have a solution:
 <string name="styled_welcome_message"><![CDATA[We are <b> %1$s </b>  glad to see you.]]></string>

inside class:
textView?.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getString(R.string.styled_welcome_message, "sample"), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)

Answer (score 62):

Use html tag inside string resources :-

```
<resources>
<string name="string_resource_name"><![CDATA[<b> Your text </b>]]> </string>
</resources>
```

And get bold text from string resources like :-

```
private Spanned getSpannedText(String text) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
        } else {
            return Html.fromHtml(text);
        }
    }


 String s = format(context.getResources().getString(R.string.string_resource_name));
 textView.setText(getSpannedText(s));
```

Comment: it is the best answer and it totally works for the people that use @BindingAdapter . Thank you, brother.

Comment: it also solves containing styles around params to the string itself +1

Answer (score 53):

As David Olsson has said, you can use HTML in your string resources:

```
<resource>
    <string name="my_string">A string with <i>actual</i> <b>formatting</b>!</string>
</resources>
```

Then if you use `getText(R.string.my_string)` rather than `getString(R.string.my_string)` you get back a `CharSequence` rather than a `String` that contains the formatting embedded.

Comment: getText returns CharSequence not a Spannable

Comment: What if your string is a quantity that you need to add a number to?

Comment: getText doesn't allow you to use placeholders

Answer (score 13):

In kotlin, you can create extensions functions on resources (activities|fragments |context) that will convert your string to an html span

e.g.

```
fun Resources.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int): Spanned = getString(id).toHtmlSpan()

fun Resources.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = getString(id, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()

fun Resources.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int): Spanned = getQuantityString(id, quantity).toHtmlSpan()

fun Resources.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = getQuantityString(id, quantity, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()

fun String.toHtmlSpan(): Spanned = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(this)
}
```

**Usage**

```
//your strings.xml
<string name="greeting"><![CDATA[<b>Hello %s!</b><br>]]>This is newline</string>

//in your fragment or activity
resources.getHtmlSpannedString(R.string.greeting, "World")
```

**EDIT even more extensions**

```
fun Context.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int): Spanned = getString(id).toHtmlSpan()

fun Context.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = getString(id, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()

fun Context.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int): Spanned = resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity).toHtmlSpan()

fun Context.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()


fun Activity.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int): Spanned = getString(id).toHtmlSpan()

fun Activity.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = getString(id, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()

fun Activity.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int): Spanned = resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity).toHtmlSpan()

fun Activity.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()


fun Fragment.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int): Spanned = getString(id).toHtmlSpan()

fun Fragment.getHtmlSpannedString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = getString(id, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()

fun Fragment.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int): Spanned = resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity).toHtmlSpan()

fun Fragment.getQuantityHtmlSpannedString(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): Spanned = resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity, *formatArgs).toHtmlSpan()
```

Comment: @Himanshu Mori some snippet would help. Are you using it in kotlin class?

Comment: Activity extensions are not necessary, Activity is Context itself

Answer (score 8):

**Simple and Latest answer** from the official Android site *(that uses placeholders like **%s** or **%1$s**)*: [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML)

First, you will add the string in your `strings.xml` like this:

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome to <b>Android</b> %1$s, %2$s!</string>
```

Here you will replace the `<` before the b with `&lt;`

To be like this:

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome to &lt;b>Android&lt;/b> %1$s, %2$s!</string>
```

In kotlin code you will make an extension to parse strings from html:

```
fun String.fromHtml(): Spanned {
return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    // FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY is the behaviour that was used for versions below android N
    // we are using this flag to give a consistent behaviour
    Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(this)
 }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
val escapedString: String = TextUtils.htmlEncode("programmers & friends")
val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
textView.text = getString(R.string.welcome, "Studio", escapedString).fromHtml()
```

OUTPUT: Welcome to **Android** Studio, programmers & friends!

Comment: this should now be the correct answer, only note that there is HtmlCompat class and no need anymore extended-function 'fromHtml'

Answer (score 6):

Strings.xml

```
<string name="my_text"><Data><![CDATA[<b>Your text</b>]]></Data></string>
```

To set

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.activity_completed_text)));
```

Comment: Html.fromHtml is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

here it's the solution for if there have any assigned values inside the string.xml file.

```
 <string name="styled_welcome_message"><![CDATA[We are <b> %1$s </b>  glad to see you.]]></string>
```

set in to TextView:

```
textView?.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getString(R.string.styled_welcome_message, "sample"), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

**PS: don't forget to wrap your text (in String Resources) within:**

```
<![CDATA[ YOUR TEXT HERE ]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from string

```
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 <string name="total_review"><b>Total Review: </b> </string>

 </resources>
```

and can access it from the java code like

```
proDuctReviewNumber.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.total_review)+productDetailsSuccess.getProductTotalReview());
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin I have created an extension function for the Context. It takes a **@StringRes** and optionally you can provide parameters as well.

```
fun Context.fromHtmlWithParams(@StringRes stringRes: Int, parameter : String? = null) : Spanned {

    val stringText = if (parameter.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    this.getString(stringRes)
                } else {
                    this.getString(stringRes, parameter)
                }

    return Html.fromHtml(stringText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

}
```

**Usage**

```
tv_directors.text = context?.fromHtmlWithParams(R.string.directors, movie.Director)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store formatted as a string variable and reuse it to text view isn't possible

> If you aren't applying formatting, you can set TextView text directly
> by calling setText(java.lang.CharSequence). In some cases, however,
> **you may want to create a styled text resource that is also used as a format string**. Normally, this doesn't work because the
> format(String, Object...) and getString(int, Object...) methods
> **strip** all the style information from the string. The work-around to this is to write the HTML tags with escaped entities, which are
> then recovered with fromHtml(String), after the formatting takes
> place.

by from docs so alternatively store the string id and everyttime bind get string from using Htlm.fromHtml().. method.

ex:

Kotlin extention

```
fun Context.getStringFromResource(stringId: Int): Spanned {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml(java.lang.String.format(resources.getString(stringId)), 
 Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml(java.lang.String.format(resources.getString(stringId)))
    }
}
```

In code:

```
getStringFromResource(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also native support for the same, where we don't have to hardcode any string or index and it plays way better in internalisation of the strings

You can define the strings like below in strings.xml as that will help in the translation of the string in other languages as well

```xml
<string name="styled_hello_world"><annotation type="bold">bold text</annotation> Hello World</string>
```

You can apply string id in your `TextView` in your UI XML.

And in the code, you can write something like below

```kotlin
val spannedText = textView.text as SpannedString
// get all the annotation spans from the text
val annotations = spannedText.getSpans(0, spannedText.length, android.text.Annotation::class.java)
val spannableString = SpannableString(spannedText)
annotations.forEach { annotation ->
    if (annotation.key == "type") {
        val styleValue = annotation.value
        if (styleValue == "bold") {
            spannableString.setSpan(
                StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                spannedText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                spannedText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
    }
}
textView.text = spannableString
```

You can find more details in the [blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f)

Answer (score 0):

strings.xml

```
<string name="sentence">This price is <b>%1$s</b> USD</string>
```

page.java

```
String successMessage = getText(R.string.message,"5.21");
```

This price **5.21** USD

Comment: You should use native functionality for passing parameters. Just place "%1$s" instead of "{1}", and call getString(R.string.message, "5.21") without replace()

Comment: The docs support this answer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML
Though it does need to be passed through an HTML parser

Comment: This answer is not correct. (or at least the last edit). The method getText(int) takes only one parameter - the string resource id. @Jemshit Iskenderov please check your edit

Comment: @AlexBusuioc ik, either way its incorrect, i downvoted. If u use getString, bold format is gone. If you use getText, argument is gone

Comment: getText doesn't support additional values

Answer (score 0):

I was having a text something like:

Forgot Password? Reset here.

To implement this the easy way I used the existing android:textStyle="bold"

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"

            android:text="Forgot password? "
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"

            android:text="Reset here"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Maybe it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use basic HTML tags in a string resource, it is necessary to escape the tags, otherwise they are ignored.
Simply, replace '<' with &lt; and '>' with '&gt;'
e.g:

```
<string name="bold_statement">This is a &lt;bold&gt; statement</string>
```

Will produce: This is a **bold** statement.
When loading the String resource, make sure to use

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(stringFromResource, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you want nicely formatted string like this:

[image]

I do this:

```
    <string name="dialog_upgrade_item_fx_output_text">
 "[B]Unlimited support for up to 5 audio effects per audio track[/B]\n
 - Multiple high quality effects available Reverb, Delay, Distortion, Compressor, Equalizer\n
 - Each comes with various presets or create your own"
    </string>

fun Context.formatted(resId: Int): Spanned =
    Html.fromHtml(getString(resId).replace("\n", "<br>")
        .replace("[B]", "<b>").replace("[/B]", "</b>"), 0)

textView(R.id.dialog_upgrade_item_text)
            .text(formatted(R.string.dialog_upgrade_item_fx_output_text))
```