# android - Highlight searched/filtered text in Expandable listview child items

Tags: android, search, filter, expandablelistview, highlighting

For my college  project I am using this sample-code [example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html), project worked successfully  and now I want to highlight searched text, but I don't kn how to implement it ,some of spanned-string example tried but does not support so any one please help me (as like as [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905028/highlight-searched-text-in-listview-items))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to highlight searched term try below code:

```
        String m_filterVal = m_searchTerm;//Your search term suppose "p"
        String m_originalItemValue = ... //Your original whole string suppose "paint";

            int m_startPos = m_originalItemValue.toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(m_filterVal.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            int m_endPos = m_startPos + m_filterVal.length();
            if (m_startPos != -1) // This should always be true, just a sanity check
            {
                Spannable m_spannable = new SpannableString(m_originalItemValue);
                ColorStateList m_blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new int[] {} }, new int[] { Color.BLUE });
                TextAppearanceSpan m_highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, m_blueColor, null);
                m_spannable.setSpan(m_highlightSpan, m_startPos, m_endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                m_tvCategoryItem.setText(m_spannable);//your textview name
            }
            else
            {
                m_tvCategoryItem.setText(m_originalItemValue);
            }
```