# how to customise text view thickness through paint (other than text size and style)

Tags: android, paint, drawtext

I am drawing text through paint, and have to set text thickness based on text frequency other than text size and text style. I am using the following code but wanted to set thickness dynamically along with this.

```
mPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
```

Comment: please describe what you want

Comment: want to set text thickness@  anddevmanu

Comment: use spanned string for that , or use html text for setting thickness like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979821/how-to-make-part-of-the-text-bold-in-android-at-runtime
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold

Comment: I am having multiple texts, wanted to set thickness based on text count. I think spanned string is not useful in this case