# How to set part of text in textView "bold" (or) "italics" style?

Tags: android, textview

I want to style few parts of texts in `textView` with **bold** (or) *italics*. (through strings.xml)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set TextView style (bold or italic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic)

Comment: You can use **Spannable String**  to change text style dynamically.

Comment: If you are looking to do it at run time you can do it with SpannableString , have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58345640/11166067

Comment: @NPovlsen, no that question asks specifically how to do it via java not through xml. But my case is different, just letting know there is alternate simple way as well.

Comment: @Velu not even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200598/9261932)? I know that it is java too, but it is a simple way

Comment: @NPovlsen, Yes it's in java and simple way compared to other suggested answer. But my requirement is to do it at compile time itself. And it also helps in localisation if the strings are in xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class StringUtil

```
class StringUtil {

    lateinit var ss: SpannableString
    fun addForegroundColorSpan(color: Int, start: Int, end: Int): StringUtil {
        ss.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        return ssu
    }
    fun addStyleSpan(style: Int, start: Int, end: Int): StringUtil {
        ss.setSpan(StyleSpan(style), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        return ssu
    }

    fun addClickableSpan(cs: ClickableSpan, start: Int, end: Int): StringUtil {
        ss.setSpan(cs, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        return ssu
    }

    fun setMovementMethod(textview: TextView): StringUtil {
        textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
        return ssu
    }

    fun getClickableSpan(url: String,context: Context): ClickableSpan {
        return object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(url)
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    fun setSpannableString(textview: TextView) {
        textview.text = ss
    }

    fun getSS(text: String): StringUtil {
        ss = SpannableString(text)
        return ssu
    }

    fun setPrefixString(edt: EditText, prefixString: String) {
        edt.setText(prefixString)
        Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length);

        edt.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if(!s.toString().startsWith(prefixString)){
                    edt.setText(prefixString);
                    Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length);

                }

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                count: Int, after: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                before: Int, count: Int
            ) {

            }
        })
    }

    companion object {
        private var ssu: StringUtil = StringUtil()
        fun getInstance(): StringUtil {
            return ssu
        }

    }
}
```

Use it like

```
StringUtil.getInstance().getSS("Here your text. You can set color Span , Style Span, Click Span for the specific part of your string.")
        .addStyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD,34,39)
        .addClickableSpan(StringUtil.getInstance().getClickableSpan("http://www.google.com",this), 34, 39)
        .addForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW, 34, 39)
        .addStyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD,43,text.length-1)
        .addClickableSpan(StringUtil.getInstance().getClickableSpan("http://www.facebook.com",this), 43, text.length-1)
        .addForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW, 43, text.length-1 )
        .setMovementMethod(binding.tvWarringPrivacyPolicy)
        .setSpannableString(binding.tvWarringPrivacyPolicy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Android textView supports lightweight HTML markup: `<b>, <u>, <i>`

```
<resources>
    <string name="b">This has <b>bold</b> in it.</string>
    <string name="i">Whereas this has <i>italics</i>!</string>
</resources>
```