# How to adjust index in a string after removing some characters?

Tags: android, regex, textview, spannablestring

I am very new to regex and text manipulation so this might be trivial for many but it is turning out to be quite a nuisance for me.

I have a string like so:

> *text* text text text *text*

where the text b/w the * denotes the text that has to be bold
So the desired output is

> **text** text text text **text**

I am halfway there using the following code

```
 val string = "*text* text text text *text*"
        val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*")
        val matcher = pattern.matcher(string)
        val spannableString = SpannableString(string)
        var counter = 0
        val indexes = IntArray(1)

        while (matcher.find()) {
                if(counter==0){
                    indexes[0]=matcher.start()
                    counter+=1
                }else if(counter==1){
                spannableString.setSpan(
                    StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                    indexes[0],matcher.start(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
               counter+=1

            }
            if(counter==2){
                counter=0
            }
        }
        textView.text = spannableString
    }
```

The output right now is
***text*** text text text ***text*** (the *s are bold as well)
I want to remove the *'s 
I intend to use

```
val spannableString = SpannableString(string.replace("*",""))
```

to remove the *'s but after that, I am not able to adjust the indexes that need to be passed on. How do I do it? or is there a better way? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I implemented what you wanted in JavaScript. It should be somewhat similar in the language you are using.

The regex explained:

- find an `*`
- capture one or more non-`*` characters in between the asterisks `([^*]+)`
- find a second `*`
- capture all matched `g` flag
- replace the matches with the captured group `$1` (and the tags).

```js
let string = '*text* text text text *text*';
string = string.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<span id='span'></span>
```

PS: if you omit the `strong` tags in the string it will just remove the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don't really need a regex to solve your problem (There's a famous saying *"If you're trying to solve a problem with RegEx, now you have 2 problems"*, and I use RegExs frequently enough to both agree and disagree).

You can use the `indexOf` method in `String` in a loop ([Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)), [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of.html)) to find the `*`s, while constructing your end result in a [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder):

- Keep a variable pointing to the start of the current span (or -1 if no open spans).
- In every iteration, you use `indexOf` starting from the last index found.
- Every time you find an opening `*` you append the text from the last position to the current one to your builder.
- Every time you find a closing `*` you append the text from the opening `*` to the closer, and set it as a bold span.
- If you don't find a `*` at an iteration you append everything from the last stop to the builder
- If you reach the end of the string and have an open `*` that was never closed you know you have an error. You can either apply a bold span or not (or `throw`).

Hope this helps.

Also, please don't hijack other questions with links to yours.

Comment: highjack..I like the sound of that :)