# Bold a text and have it in next line for a particular string in Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string

I am trying to bold a particular word in a string that is stored in strings.xml:

Here is what I would like to have it as:

Future tense: **Example:** I will be there at 9:00AM

I followed this: [Bold words in a string of strings.xml in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130619/bold-words-in-a-string-of-strings-xml-in-android) - But didn't get the results.

so I had text in strings.xml like:

```
<string name="futureText">Future tense: <b>Example:</b> I will be there at 9:00AM</string>

Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.futureText));
questionText.setText (text);
```

I am not getting any bold for "Example:".

Also how to get the "Example: I will be there at 9:00AM" text to next line? I know in string \n goes to next how about in html format?

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not really read the html tag within the string.xml because it is a default tag within the xml so by the time you read it programatically it wont read the tag but just its text without the tag.

**solution:**

you need to wrap it in `<![CDATA[ ...raw html... ]]>` to enable you to read the html tag within the text.

**sample:**

```
<string name="futureText">Future tense: <![CDATA[<b>Example:</b>]]> I will be there at 9:00AM</string>
```