# Set some words in text taken from XML to bold

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to display, with enhancements, a text taken from inside a pair of tags in an XML file. Here are the opening tag, the text, and the closing tag:

> `<english><strong>English adjectives: a young woman</strong></br> They are always invariable in gender and number.</english>`

But instead of viewing the enhanced text, all I see is exactly the above text between the `<english>` and `</english>` tags, with the things like `<strong>` included. How can I solve this?

Here is the method to read the XML file:

```java
public void lireXML(String mot)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{

    final TextView monMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone_trado_scrollable);

    XmlResourceParser monFichierXML = getResources().getXml(R.xml.text);

    monFichierXML.next();

    int eventType = monFichierXML.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        if( (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) && (monFichierXML.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("word"))  )
        {
            monFichierXML.next();
            if ( monFichierXML.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(mot) )
            {

                monFichierXML.nextTag(); // word fermant
                monFichierXML.nextTag(); // english ouvrant
                monFichierXML.next();    // texte anglais

                if (langueChoisie == "francais") {
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // english fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // français ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte français
                }

                if (langueChoisie == "espanol") {
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // english fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // français ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte français
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // français fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // espanol ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte espanol
                }

                if (langueChoisie == "chinois") {
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // english fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // français ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte français
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // français fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // espanol ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte espanol
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // espagnol fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // russe ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte russe
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // russe fermant
                    monFichierXML.nextTag(); // chinois ouvrant
                    monFichierXML.next();    // texte chinois
                }

                // on affiche le texte à l'intérieur de la balise sélectionnée
                monMessage.setText(monFichierXML.getText());
            }
        }
        eventType = monFichierXML.next();
    }
}`
```

And here is a bit of XML:

```xml
<group>
    <word>young1</word>
    <english><strong>English adjectives: a young woman</strong> <br>They are always invariable in gender and number.</english>
    <francais><strong>Les adjectifs: a young woman</strong> <br>Les adjectifs qualificatifs anglais sont invariables. Quand ils sont épithètes, ils se placent avant le substantif: a young woman. Quand ils sont attributs, ils se placent après le verbe: the woman is young.</francais>
    <espanol><strong>Los adjetivos: a young woman</strong> <br>Los adjetivos en inglés son invariables. Cuando son calificativos, se colocan delante del sustantivo: a young woman. Cuando son atributos, se colocan después del verbo: the woman is young.</espanol>
    <chinois><strong>英语形容词：一位年轻的女士。</strong> <br>不论性别和数量都一样</chinois>
</group>`
```

Comment: How are you trying to display?

Comment: I use a method, but I can't show it in this comment :-(

Comment: You can update your question and paste your method.

Comment: Without your code it would be harder answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use html tags with a TextView you should use:

```
 monMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(monFichierXML.getText()));
```

Comment: It seems to me, this will be an entirely different architecture. Is it possible while still reading xml?

Comment: The xml is not directly relevant, you just put the html inside Html.fromHtml('your html').
It doesn't matter where you got the html from.

Comment: The function fromHtml is now deprecated (Android > N). You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
TextView myTextview;

myTextview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

htmltext = <your html (markup) character>;

Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml( htmltext );

myTextview.setText(sp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<b>English adjectives: a young woman</b> <br>They are always invariable in gender and number.
```

If this fails just encode the `<` character as `&lt;`, resulting in:

```
&lt;b>English adjectives: a young woman&lt;/b> <br>They are always invariable in gender and number.
```

Check this answer for more information [Bold words in a string of strings.xml in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130619/bold-words-in-a-string-of-strings-xml-in-android)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work (be it &#60;strong&#62; or &lt;...)

Comment: How are you displaying the string afterwards?