# how to style text store in string xml inside double quotes

Tags: android

I have my text store in string xml inside double quotes

```
<string name>="value">"my text"</string>
```

How do I add style like bold italic to the text that I put inside double quotes.

Comment: Duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7130619/5130133)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<string name="title"><u><b><i>\"Nilesh Rathod\"</i></b></u></string>
```

Comment: It will be helpful for me i future... Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add it like below

```
<string name>="value">\"my text\"</string>
```

and it will show double quotes when you use it.