# How to format Java Strings in the Java class not using the xml

Tags: java, android

I have a String array list set up to populate text to multiple intro screens. As the text is populated in the actualy Java class and not in the xml resource file I want to know how can I make certain words in the text bold from within the java class?

```
 public String [] slide_descriptions = {
        "I want this text in bold \n",
        "and maybe this too!"
};
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130619/bold-words-in-a-string-of-strings-xml-in-android

Comment: Thats for xml, I need to make it bold directly into the java file

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html tags. For example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("< b >This is Bold< /b >"));
```

For String, do it like this:

```
 public String [] slide_descriptions = {
        "<b>I want this text in bold</b> \n",
        "<b>and maybe this too!</b>"
};
```

So at the end when you put the string in the textview:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(slide_description));
```

Comment: Lux you use html with TextView not String. I edited the answer

Comment: You can't just add <b> into the string otherwise it just prints <b> out with the rest of the string.......

Comment: Lux you are textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(slide_description));

Answer (score 0):

See answer below: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371107/11251645)

However in comment says that *This will slow down performance.*

Comment: Thats all for the xml file, I cant write like that in the java file?

Comment: What do you mean "in java file"? You need bold text inside java file? Not on the output?

Comment: There's to files the java class and the xml. I'm using the java to populate a slider screen. So there's one xml file but 5 slider screens. So all the text that is displayed is stored in the java class as a string and populated into a textview box. So I need to highlight specific words in the java string in the java class. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spannable string as it is easy and less costly

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(yourstringhere);
spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),indexStart,indexEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Can you add that spannable string code into the code I put in my question so I can see how it's structured / implemented

Comment: `String stringToBold = "I want this text in bold"; SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(stringToBold);
spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),0,stringToBold.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`