# Android: How to append formatted text to android.text.Editable?

Tags: android, textview

Within a `TagHandler` which I passed to `Html.fromHtml()`, I would like to append some formatted text to the given `Editable output` object, which then gets passed to a `TextView`.

Appending plain text with `output.append("my text")` works fine. But how to append red or italic text?

```
class MyTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {

  @Override
  public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
    output.append("my text");
    // how to append red and italic text here ?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `Html.fromHtml` and `Editable.setSpan()` to do it. Here's some sample code:

```
    appendFormatted(output, "<font color=red><i>red italic</i></font>");
}

private void appendFormatted(Editable text, String string) {
    final int start = text.length();
    final Spanned span = Html.fromHtml(string);
    text.append(span);
    final int end = text.length();
    for (final Object o : span.getSpans(0, span.length(), Object.class)) {
        text.setSpan(o, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

If you just need some simple formatting applied, you can pass in the specific [`CharacterStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) derived-object to the `Editable.setSpan()` call - see the ["Selecting, Highlighting, or Styling Portions of Text" example](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext) on the developers site.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right here is a way to do this

```
mBox = new TextView(context);
mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + description + "</small>" + "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + DateAdded + "</small>"));
```

The answer was copied from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview).

Comment: I want append formatted text to android.text.Editable, not to a HTML string.