# Different colors in TextView defined in XML

Tags: android

I want to define different colors in single TextView like below:

```
<font color="yellow">Hi </font><font color="red">everybody</font>
```

I saw this link: [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview). But it doesn't suit me. I would like to know how can I define it via XML. Is it possible to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry we can do only in source code. Would be curious if we can do in xml. Can you tell why can't u use it by source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can't set in XML file but we can set as coding...
You have to use text spannable..
here is example..

> String text = "Hi @@hello@@";
>
> TextView.setText(setSpanBetweenTokens(text, "@@", new
> ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED)));

your setSpanBetweenTokens Method

> 

```
public static CharSequence setSpanBetweenTokens(CharSequence text,
            String token, CharacterStyle... cs)
        {
            // Start and end refer to the points where the span will apply
            int tokenLen = token.length();
            int start = text.toString().indexOf(token) + tokenLen;
            int end = text.toString().indexOf(token, start);
        

if (start > -1 && end > -1)
```

> ```
>       {               
>           SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
>           for (CharacterStyle c : cs)
>               ssb.setSpan(c, start, end, 0);
>
>           // Delete the tokens before and after the span
>           ssb.delete(end, end + tokenLen);
>           ssb.delete(start - tokenLen, start);
>
>           text = ssb;
>       }
>       return text;
>   }
> ```