# Change text color within a string?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different colors in TextView defined in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784422/different-colors-in-textview-defined-in-xml)

This is probably a really stupid question but I couldn't figure this out.
What I want to do is change the color of the text within the string, like so:
"Hi, how are" +colorRed " you?"

^ trying to change the word "you" to be the color red.

Comment: Agree with @Pearsonartphoto - and note that this is not supported by all Views.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I know is to just use html.

```
String color = "Hi, how are <font color='#EE0000'>you</font>";
**YOUR_TEXTVIEW**.setText(Html.fromHtml(color));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "Hi, how are <font color='red'>you</font>?";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best (and less time-consuming) way is - use a [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html). For example:

```
final String text = "Hi, how are ";
final Spannable spanYou = new SpannableString("you");
spanYou.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, spanYou.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(text);
textView.append(spanYou);
```

[Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) at first parse your text as html, and use Spannable after.