# Android Color specific words in an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that has many words. I want to color specific words in it, Is that possible? How can I achieve that?

**ex.** I have this in my `ArrayList`:

> I love ferrari cars, because they are #Awesome!

How can I make Awesome a different color? and how can I color the punctuatuions (, and !)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

first one is

```
    SpannableString WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("This is simple");        
    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//0 is starting character and 7 is ending character you need to specify it


  textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

and the second is

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**EDIT:**

```
String txt = "partial colored #text";
        int to_len = txt.length();
        int sim_pos = txt.indexOf("#");

        SpannableString WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(txt);        
          WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), sim_pos, to_len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: I couldn't get it, can you guide me more about how to use SpannableString with my arraylist to detect the # or punctuation ?

Comment: @JohnJared no it'll not detect # or punctuation. just give from starting character position to ending character position.

Comment: @JohnJared From your point of view use second one from adding `String` to `ArrayList` for that particular word give like that.

Comment: Thank you, characters from 0-7 has been colored. But that is not what I have asked for, please re read the question

Comment: @JohnJared have you check my ans

Answer (score 1):

You can either use spannable string or if you use HTML you can load text view from HTML text. You can see  example over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501856/change-text-color-within-a-string)

Comment: can you explain it more?

Comment: If # is going to appear you can give element.indexof("#") and end element ad length of element