# android customize text in textview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

i wonder if we can do this in android or not , i have textview ,which has text as :

( hi  everybody how are you) for example, can we customize programmatically each word in

the same textview :

like :

hi = bold + small size + blue in color.

everybody = normal + red in color +large size.

how are you = italic and use custom font + normal size .

please if we can ,would you please tell me how we can do it programmatically .

thanks alot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Comment: @thinksteep You can vote to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `Html.fromHtml("blah blah blah")` to convert from html formatted text. Always works like a charm!