# set two differemt color in one textview dynamically

Tags: android

Hello Friends i set two different color in single textview like below
[image: Output Screen]

My code is as below

```
public static String getAnswers(List<Question> questions) {
    int question = 1;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Question q : questions){
        String d= "<font color=#292929>" +   sb.append("Q").append(question).append(") ").append(q.getQuestion()).append("? \n")+"</font>";
        String ss="<font color=#ce4e00>"+sb.append("Answer: ").append(q.getAnswer()).append("\n\n")+"</font>";

            AnswersActivity.results.setText(Html.fromHtml(d+ss),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        question ++;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

and is textview i set

```
        mStringQustion = Utility.getAnswers(currentGame.getQuestions());
```

and get output like below

[image: Output iMAge]

How can i solve it ?

Comment: try this code for black #000000 and this for orange #FF4500

Comment: Why not a `TextView` for each row ? easier ... ?!

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141156/254567) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14936995/254567)

Answer (score 2):

I have came across the same problem and i fixed it like below

You should use **ForegroundColorSpan**

```
String firstString = "Book Title:";
String secondString = "Book Description";
String thirdString = "1.SubTitle";

        SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                firstString + "\n" + secondString + "\n" + thirdString);
        stringBuilder.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f), 0,
                firstString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        stringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(
                android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), firstString.length(),
                firstString.length() + secondString.length() + 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        stringBuilder.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)),
                firstString.length() + secondString.length() + 1,
                firstString.length() + secondString.length()
                        + thirdString.length() + 2,
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        AnswersActivity.results.setText.setText(stringBuilder);
```

[image]

You can change it according to your text.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String d = "&lt;![CDATA[ &lt;font color=#292929>" + sb.append("Q").append(question).append(")").append(q.getQuestion()).append("? \n")+"</font>";  
String ss="<font color=#ce4e00>" + sb.append("Answer:").append(q.getAnswer()).append("\n\n")+"</font>]]>";
```