# Colours of strings used in a text view programmatically

Tags: java, android, textview

Is it possible to set colours of strings used in a text view programmatically? I tried using this but it doesn't work.

```
TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0099CC'>@string/app_name</font>" +
                        "<font color='#995676'> @string/app_description</font>" +
                        "<font color='#55GGFES'> @string/app_version</font>"
        ));
```

Comment: Nope, because I need to use multiple strings in 1 text view

Comment: we have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140893/android-multi-color-in-one-textview which is actually a duplicate of another :) sorry, didn't read totally carefully

Comment: If it is a duplicate, please remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but not this easily.  You can't just inject @string/ inside of a string in Java that way.  What you can use is `context.getResources().getString(R.id.app_name);` to get the name.  So like this:

```
    txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0099CC'>"+
         context.getResources().getString(R.id.app_name)+"</font>"+
         "<font color='#995676'>"+
         context.getResources().getString(R.id.app_description)+"</font>"));
```

Comment: Could you show the use of 2 strings please?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a spannable.

```
String mString = context.getResources().getString(R.id.app_name);
Spannable coloredSpan = new SpannableString(mString);        
//Spannable.setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)

coloredSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, mString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

txt.setText(coloredSpan);
```