# Can we write colorful text in the same EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use Android Studio. I want to write colorful text like in the photo below in the same `EditText`. I have researched but I have found nothing. Can anyone help me?

The sample output is below.

[image: photo]

This is my code: `anaM_LV_BG_text` is a list view
`name_title` and content are edittext
`renk_koduları_string_text` is an array that includes html colors

```
   private void registerClickCallBack_text() {
        anaM_LV_BG_renk_text.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(DisplayNote.this, position + 1 + " . seçildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                name_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(renk_koduları_string_text[position]));
                content.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(renk_koduları_string_text[position]));
               SharedPreferences preferences_text = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor_text = preferences_text.edit();

                String color_text= renk_koduları_string_text[position];
                editor_text.putString("MyColorText",color_text);
                editor_text.commit();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141022/5425930

Answer (score 5):

Use a `SpannableString`

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("This is a wonderful day");        
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editText.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: can i use this?

Comment: i use list view. When i click list view color is changed. i have color_array from xml file. I use setOnItemClickListener and i get text from edittext.getText().toString. can i use this line like below?
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(array_color[position]), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a string with an "**html tag**" and while you are integrating it in the `EditText` just use this method: `Html.fromHtml()`.

Example:

```
String strData =  "<b>Hi</b> <i>I am</i> programmer"</br>
myEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(strData));
```