# Android list view new line (\n) different color?

Tags: android, xml, styles, android-listview, newline

I have a list view where I have 2 lines for every item. That looks like so:

```
Title of item1

Subtitle of item1
```

I was wondering if there is a way to change the color and size of the 2nd line by code? 
They both share 1 `TextView` so I can't just edit that. I could use 2 text views but I'm not sure how to set that up. 
I am using a custom xml for the list view though.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

---

Here is my custom list view xml:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_margin="7dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#474747"
         />
 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Here is how I'm assigning the xml to the list view:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row, R.id.label, arrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: You really should have two text views in each list item.  You can create custom adapter and set details of each text view for an item.

Comment: [style Text View with Multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ArrayAdapter with tow Textview

Using simple_list_item_2 with an ArrayAdapter

as in [link](http://www.sethgholson.com/2012/01/using-simple_list_item_2-with-an-arrayadapter-android/)

and as per link you 'll get the text View using  row.getText1(), row.getText2() so you can set the color their

or

can use custom  Adapter as in [link](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/android/android-two-line-listview-with-custom-data.html)