# Different textsizes in a button

Tags: android, button, text-formatting

I want to create a button.
This button contains a letter with a size of 22pixels and some letters to the right of it with a size of 16  pixels.

Like this:
 [image]

How can I achieve this?

At the moment I have this:

```
private void setText(Button btn, String text, String underText) {
    Spannable span = new SpannableString(text + "\n" +  underText);

    btn.setText(span);
}
```

Comment: Lock at this 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can apply `AbsoluteSizeSpan` in your Spannable to make different size of Text in same content.

```
 private void setText(Button btn, String text, String underText) {

    Spannable span = new SpannableString(text + "\n" +  underText);
    span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(fontSize), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    btn.setText(span);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this sollution for a BUTTON but it is not working

Answer (score 7):

Instead of doing it through code, you may simply achieve it by using **html** stuff in *string resource*. For example:

Define a string resource:

```
<string name="tmp"><font size="30">2</font>abc</string>
```

and apply it to your button's text:

```
android:text="@string/tmp"
```

Comment: i believe dimensions related to html are in pixels

Comment: While this works it is incredibly slow... if you're updating the text often or have lot of these cases in your view hierachy, don't use it
SpannabelStringBuilders API might not be pretty, but it's fast