# How to set different text size to one button in android?

Tags: android, android-button

I have a button in that i want two different text size to be displayed. i have declared that text into string.xml and i have set text in java code by `btnSin.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.lblasin) + "\n"
                + getResources().getString(R.string.lblSin));`
 so what is the way to do so.

Comment: Same logic applies for buttons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193785/different-textsizes-in-a-button this is what u were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the two strings in [AbsoluteSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.html) objects

Answer (score 5):

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanSin = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    SpannableString itemasin = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.lblasin)+"\n");
    itemasin.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(9, true), 0,itemasin.length(),0);
    itemasin.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#EA7C07")), 0, itemasin.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spanSin.append(itemasin);

    SpannableString itemsin = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.lblSin));
    itemsin.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(12, true), 0,itemsin.length(),0);
    spanSin.append(itemsin);
    btnSin.setText(spanSin,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```