# how to split a textview into multiple rows and set each row a different style

Tags: android

Is it possible to split a textView into multiple rows and have a style for each row?

for example i would like to have in a textview:

" **Row1** //color black and bold

Row2 //different font and color"

this is my layout xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:text="Name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

I'm setting the text view s text with :

```
      textView.setText("Row1 /n Row2");
```

Is it possible to ad a table inside the textView and change each row's style?

How can i do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use multiple TextViews for this purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Html.fromhtml()` to add different colors and fonts to text and to add another line in TextView simply use "\n"

Example: `textview.setText("text1"+"\n"+"text2")`

Example for Html.fromhtml(): `text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>text</font>"));`