# Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries) When Add resources to Array

Tags: android, arrays

When I try to get all references into array I get error. Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries).

I try to read all strings into Array like:

```
String[] aStrings = mAppContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_array)
```

in  xml i have 500+ lines of strings, like:

```
<string-array name="a_array">
    <item>0@100@Name1</item>
    <item>1@101@name2</item>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <item>600@101@name600</item>
</string-array>
```

If i run my code in for exemple note2(4.+) everything works ok, if I run it in wildfire(2.+) I get error. If i reduce entries bellow 500 then everything works ok. I belive that error that I get is because of low memory on older device. When error happens applicatin crash.

Now I got two questions:

1. can I avoid this error? somehow fix this? so that my app woun't crash.
2. is there a way to catch this error and load smaller array? (I tryed with try catch block, but no success)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix the problem. Insted of creating `<string-array name="a_array">` I created:

```
<string name="a_array">
  0@100@Name1#
  1@101@name2#
  ...
  ...
  N@N@nameN
</string>
```

And than i read string into variable, and with `.split("#");` parse it into array.