# TextView with different sizes

Tags: android, textview

In my layout, I have defined a `TextView` and have given it the id - `textName`.

Programmatically, I have set its text to `My name is Blah`. I was wondering if it is possible to programmatically increase the `textsize` of just `Blah` and not the whole `TextView`?

Comment: put "my name is" and blah in separate textview

Comment: I am not sure abt this. But this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533512/1858914

Comment: @appubala I thought about that but I don't want to add a separate textView as there are a lot of instances where I want to change the size of just one word in a TextView. Adding another textview to all of them will be tedious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or simply using the Spannable class:

```
String text = textView.getText();
Spannable span = new SpannableString(text);
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), text.indexOf("Blah"), text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! you can do by formatting the string with HTML, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533512/603233

like eg

```
String text = "<h5>My name is </h5><h1>Blah</h1>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```