# In Android----How can we get word which is speaking in Text to Speech?

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

Any one help me for Provide hint in Text to Speech?

My aim is to provide hint which word is reading by devices.

Text to Speech My code is below :-

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
if (txtText.getText().toString().length() == 0) 
        tts.speak("You haven't typed text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
     else
        tts.speak(txtText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it down, word by word, and highlight the mentioned word. For e.g. if we take a sentence like "You haven't typed text":

```
 tts.speak("You", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
/*Change size or color of "You" in your TextView for e.g.*/
 tts.speak("haven't", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
/*Change size or color of "haven't" in your TextView for e.g.*/
 tts.speak("typed", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
/*Change size or color of "typed" in your TextView for e.g.*/

...
```

You can do this by using `txtText.getText().toString().Split" ";` to return a String Array of the words separated by space. Then loop through this Array to know which word is spoken and highlight it in the TextView like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview) for e.g.

Comment: Thanks. I used TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD but My Problem is not Solved because of TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD take few milliseconds and Text is bold immediate.

Comment: Try to adjust it with `Thread.Sleep(/*few millis*/);` in setting your Text Bold

Comment: Please use below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701602/in-android-how-can-we-provide-hint-which-word-is-speaking-in-text-to-speech(But it not Speaking well).