# In Android----How can we provide hint which word is speaking in Text to Speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Any body help me to Provide hint in Text to Speech?

I get word in Array but `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD` takes a few seconds to speak and makes bold word run speedily.

My Code is below :-(tts is a `TextToSpeech` object)

```
String[] strArr = txtText.getText().toString().split(" ");
txtText.setText("");
for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++)
{
   Log.d("","Value :- "+strArr[i]);
   HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
   myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
   myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "test");
   tts.speak(strArr[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,myHashAlarm);
   txtText.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + strArr[i] + "</b>"+" "));
}
```

Also I can't Understand `tts.speak` last parameter(`myHashAlarm`). How does it work?

Thanks

Comment: Glancing at the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html, myHashAlarm is a parameter map. You can put an "utterance id" inside and use an listenere using setUtteranceProgressListener.  Each Parameter map must contain a unique utterance id, and you're listener will be called for every utterance id.